# React-Redux why when I set up a middleware the object is returned twice when is called

Tags: javascript, redux

This is the 2 objects when a make a axios fetch and then set the response.data into the store

[image: Returned 2 Objects]

[image]

My Question is if this is normal, because the default State is empty, so first return the empty object and then the filled object, how can i solve tha
or is something happening for a bit delayed request.

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that at the begining your initial state is '[]' it does not has anything. the request is made and now your state is 
state = {
   initialState //which is an empty array
}

then you do a request again an state is equals to whatever state has plus and array of products

state = {
   [],
   products
}

you have two choices. remove `products` from the switch or add it at the initial state

```js
const initialState = {
   products: []
}


export function reducer (state = initialState, action) {

   swtich (action.type) {
     case 'getAllProducts':
     return {
       products:[...action.payload]
     }

   }

}
```